# Compare 2 lists in MbUnit 3.1

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, mbunit, gallio

I am trying to compare 2 Dictionary objects for equality in MbUnit 3.1 like so

```
Assert.AreEqual<FieldList>(expectedOutputFieldList, actualOutputFieldList);
```

Where FieldList is = `Dictionary<string, object>`

However this throws up the following "error":

*Both values look the same when formatted but they are distinct instances.*

Is there any method for comparing object data rather than instances?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Assert.AreElementsEqualIgnoringOrder(expectedOutputFieldList, actualOutputFieldList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mauricio is absolutely right. But more generally speaking, there are many useful assertions to be used with collections and enumerations in MbUnit v3. You may want to have a look at them:

- [Assert.AreElementsEqual](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsEqual.htm)
- [Assert.AreElementsEqualIgnoringOrder](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsEqualIgnoringOrder.htm)
- [Assert.AreElementsNotEqual](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsNotEqual.htm)
- [Assert.AreElementsSame](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsSame.htm)
- [Assert.AreElementsSameIgnoringOrder](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsSameIgnoringOrder.htm)
- [Assert.AreElementsNotSame](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_AreElementsNotSame.htm)
- [Assert.Exists](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_Exists.htm)
- [Assert.ForAll](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_ForAll.htm)
- [Assert.ContainsKey](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_ContainsKey.htm)
- [Assert.DoesNotContainKey](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_DoesNotContainKey.htm)
- [Assert.Contains](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_Contains.htm)
- [Assert.DoesNotContain](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_DoesNotContain.htm)
- [Assert.IsEmpty](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_IsEmpty.htm)
- [Assert.IsNotEmpty](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_IsNotEmpty.htm)
- [Assert.Distinct](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_Distinct.htm)
- [Assert.Sorted](http://gallio.org/api/html/Overload_MbUnit_Framework_Assert_Sorted.htm)